# C++ Sorting numbers in a text file

Tags: c++, sorting, fstream

I am trying to create a program in which the user inputs the amount of numbers, user choice(ascending or descending order), and the numbers themselves. Then afterwards it creates an input file("input.txt") in which it contains the amount of numbers, user choice, and the numbers themselves. Then that file is passed through a function in which it reads the input file and creates a output file("output.txt") in which contains the amount of numbers and the numbers after they are sorted. Currently it is giving me errors when the program  attempts to enter the size and I do not know why. Also I have read Absolute C++ by Walter Savitch for awnsers but I cant find where it says you can have a program read both numbers and characters in an input file.  Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. All the code is below.

```
void inputFile(int numbers[], char choice, int size)
{
ifstream inFile;
cout << "\n\n Creating input.txt"<<endl;
inFile.open("input.txt");
//checks if it fails to open
if(inFile.fail())
{
    cout<<"Error#1: Input file failed to open";
    exit(1);
}
cout<<"Inputing user choice and size"<<endl;
//Inputs choice and size into input.txt
inFile >> size >> "\n";
inFile >> choice >> "\n";
cout << "Iputing numbers"<<endl;
//inputs all the numbers
for(int x=0; x<size; x++)
{
    inFile >> numbers[x] >> "\n";
}
outputFile(inFile);
cout << "Closing input file"<<endl;
inFile.close();
}
void outputFile(ifstream& inData)
{
ofstream outFile;
cout << "Creating output.txt"<<endl;
//creates the output.txt file
outFile.open("output.txt");
//check if it fails to open
if(outFile.fail())
{
    cout<<"Error#2: Output file failed to open";
    exit(1);
}
//initilizing variables
int n=0;
int *sort;
int next;
int size;
int totalTimesTrue;
char choice;
cout << "Reading size in input.txt"<<endl;
//takes the size and puts in in the output file
while(inData >> next)
{
    if(next == '\n')
    {
        break;
    }
    size = next;
    outFile << size<<"\n";
}
//creating a dynamic array
sort = new int[size];
cout << "Reading user choice"<<endl;
//reads the user choice from the input file. (a)scending or (d)escending
inData.get(choice);
if(choice = 'a')
{
    cout<<"Sorting numbers in ascending order"<<endl;
    while(inData >> next && n<size)
    {
        if(next == '\n')
        {
            continue;
        }
        sort[n]= next;
        n++;
    }
    for(int x=0; x<size; x++)
    {
        totalTimesTrue=0;
        for(int y=0; y<size; y++)
        {
            if(sort[x]<sort[y])
            {
                totalTimesTrue++;
            }
        }
        sort[totalTimesTrue]=sort[x];
    }

}
else if(choice = 'd')
{
    cout <<"Sorting numbers in decending order"<<endl;
    while(inData >> next && n<size)
    {
        if(next == '\n')
        {
            continue;
        }
        sort[n]=next;
        n++;
    }
    for(int x=0; x<size; x++)
    {
        totalTimesTrue=0;
        for(int y=0; y<size; y++)
        {
            if(sort[x]>sort[y])
            {
                totalTimesTrue++;
            }
        }
        sort[totalTimesTrue]=sort[x];
    }
}
cout<<"Creating the output"<<endl;
for(int x=0; x<size; x++)
{
    outFile << sort[x] << "\n";
}
delete sort;
cout<<"Closing output.txt"<<endl;
outFile.close();
}
```

Comment: That's an awful lot of code. Can you please narrow it down to the places where you have your trouble.

Comment: Your code resumed in three lines: `while( user inputs numbers ) v.push_back( number readed );` `std::sort( std::begin( v ) , std::end( v ) , comparer specified by the user` `std::copy( std::begin( v ) , std::end( v ) , std::ostream_iterator<int>( file stream , '\n' ) );`

Comment: Ok I narrowed it down to just the functions. And @Manu454726 I currently do not know what push_back, sort, begin, and end does. Also what does ostream_iterator do?

Comment: [ostream_iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ostream_iterator/). push_back adds a new element at the end of the vector, after its current last element. sort sorts the elements in ascending order. begin returns the first element and end returns the last element.

Comment: Ok but I was instructed to have new lines for every element in the .txt files. Do these functions read the '\n' command?

Comment: The program seems to not enter the size because its giving me an error on the operands in the inputFile function where it says inFile >> size >> "\n"

Comment: @ToltarTheGreat `inFile >> size >> "\n"` is wrong. Just do `inFile >> size`

Comment: Thanks for finding the bug